# How can I Add to a collection that's in another page?

Tags: c#, xml, xaml

Anyone know how to add to an ObservableCollection that's in one class from another class? What I'm trying to do is when you click a button on the `CurrentTasks` page it adds a new `CurrentTask` into the `completedTaskList` that's in my `CompletedTasks` class

Current Task page

```
public partial class CurrentTasks : ContentPage
{
    private ObservableCollection<Models.CurrentTask> currentTaskList { get; set; }
    internal ObservableCollection<Models.CurrentTask> CurrentTasklist { get => currentTaskList; set => currentTaskList = value; }
    public CurrentTasks()
    {
        currentTaskList = new ObservableCollection<Models.CurrentTask>()
        {
            new Models.CurrentTask {TaskName = "First Task", TaskDescription = "Very important", Prioity = ImageSource.FromResource("LifeManager.Images.high.png")},
            new Models.CurrentTask {TaskName = "Second Task", TaskDescription = "Not as important", Prioity = ImageSource.FromResource("LifeManager.Images.low.png")}
        };
        InitializeComponent();
        listView.ItemsSource = currentTaskList;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentTask newtask = new CurrentTask { TaskName = "New task", TaskDescription = "New task Descroipti", Prioity = ImageSource.FromResource("LifeManager.Images.high.png") };
        currentTaskList.Add(newtask);
    }
}
```

Completed Tasks

```
public partial class CompletedTasks 
{
    private ObservableCollection<Models.CurrentTask> completedTaskList { get; set; }
    internal ObservableCollection<Models.CurrentTask> CompletedTaskList { get => CompletedTaskList; set => CompletedTaskList = value; }
    public CompletedTasks()
    {
        InitializeComponent();          
        completedTaskList = new ObservableCollection<Models.CurrentTask>()
        {
            new Models.CurrentTask {TaskName = "First Task", TaskDescription = "Very important", Prioity = ImageSource.FromResource("LifeManager.Images.high.png")},
            new Models.CurrentTask {TaskName = "Second Task", TaskDescription = "Not as important", Prioity = ImageSource.FromResource("LifeManager.Images.low.png")}
        };

        listView.ItemsSource = completedTaskList;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentTask newtask = new CurrentTask { TaskName = "New task", TaskDescription = "New task Descroipti", Prioity = ImageSource.FromResource("LifeManager.Images.high.png") };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the CompletedTasks object is maintained in some other window. Below example I assumed as mainWindow.

In the mainwindow you maintain the objects of CompletedTasks

And have properties to return the objects.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
        private CompletedTasks comT;

        public CompletedTasks completedTask
        {
            get { return comT; }
            set { comT = value; }
        }
..
..
..
..

}
```

Now in your page, access the main window and update the list.

Something like below.

```
public partial class CurrentTasks : ContentPage
{

....
....
....
....

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentTask newtask = new CurrentTask { TaskName = "New task", TaskDescription = "New task Descroipti", Prioity = ImageSource.FromResource("LifeManager.Images.high.png") };
        currentTaskList.Add(newtask);


       //update Here when task is done
       //Access the main window
       var mainWin = Application.Current.Windows
                .Cast<Window>()
                .FirstOrDefault(window => window is MainWindow) as MainWindow;

        mainWin.completedTask.CompletedTaskList.Add(newtask);
    }
}
```

For example I used Main Window. You can use any window.

Comment: My main window is inheritinging from the contentpage. How do i access the main page if its not a window?

Comment: If so, you can get it as App.Current.MainPage;

Comment: I tried that and it says page does not contain definition for cast